# do you know if mathematical formulas are right?

Tags: philosophy-of-mathematics

for example the formulas for some geometric figures like circles i dont remember other figures which i think the formulas are wrong for example the formula for a square it seems sound but for other it doesn is there a way to prove or disprove a formula or is it just guessing

Comment: Those formulas can be demonstrated. Also, they have been tested thoroughly by being put to use since they where researched. Architects of the antiquity used such formulas to plan for the amount of resource they needed for a given building. For example, if they wanted to build a circular colosseum they needed to evaluate the amount of stone they needed as precisely as possible. In the same way, the Pythagorean theorem was used by ancient Egyptian builders to make sure their angle were straight, to a staggering level of precision.

Comment: where is the proof of the formula of a circle?

Comment: where is the proof of the formula of a triangle?

Comment: proofs can seem counter intuitive Joseph: that's part of what makes them.

Comment: haha I remember when I didn't believe anything was logical, because we weren't taught it in mathematics class I guess.

Comment: Do you agree that once some starting point is agreed upon, from that proofs can begin to exist?

Comment: i dont know i will make more research

Comment: what is it you call the "formula of a circle" ? Like, the formula of it's surface, the formula of it's circumference ? The mere fact that you use such vague terminology is a sign that you did very few prior research.

Comment: surface the formula

Answer (score 1):

Just because you yourself do not know of the existence of geometrical proofs like that does not mean they in fact do not exist. The proofs you seek will be contained in any introductory textbook on *plane geometry*, and were known to the ancients.

But this is different from the question posed in the title. Mathematics is the art of quantitative reasoning. Each proof of a new mathematical fact or property is based directly on the next earlier proof in a hierarchy stretching back across thousands of years' worth of *solved problems* in the field.

In this context, a solved problem demonstrates the correctness and hence the utility of the underlying mathematics. If math were *not* the correct way to quantitatively reason we would have known it many thousands of years ago.

Comment: i will look for it but i dont believe it

Comment: why there is so much censorship in this place

Comment: its just i think some formulas are wrong for example the formula for the area of a circle

Comment: i changed the question

Answer (score 0):

Mathematics is a system of pure reason. It is composed of 1. (non-conflicting) definitions and 2. proofs that derive from those definitions via deductive reason. I may thus, for instance, define a circle as a figure where-in all points are equi-distant from the center. (Note: no formula needed for such a definition). I can likewise define a triangle as any three-sided figure.

If I posit that a certain formula is representative of a circle - I need to prove that for any circle with some radius R that the formula 1. includes in its set of outputs all of the points along the circle that have a distance R from the center, and 2. the formula doesn't include any points that aren’t part of that circle.

The particulars of a given proof are best researched via Google or a the mathematics forum, but hopefully this clears up how you would approach it.

Comment: hi i was removed two points after i changed the question to do you know if mathematical formulas are right? what is wrong with this site they havent provedthem and they say that the y removed two points

Comment: why is there so much censorship on internet

Comment: i posted on reddit that cells dont exist and i was banned

Comment: You are being banned, I would say, because you are making accusations without having done your homework. Nor is this the proper forum to seek mathematical proofs - there is a math stack exchange you could ask for such proofs on, however. I do think that they can be a bit overzealous at times in moderating the various stack exchange forums, but I can see why your inquiries are getting flagged. 

Not that they are bad inquiries, mind. Question away. But generally it is expected that you have done some research on your own before posting questions and accusations. Buy some books on the topic.

Comment: @joseph Also, your updated question is too broad. What do you mean by formula for a square, for instance? A square is defined as a four sided figure where all sides are the same length. I’m not familiar offhand with what formula you have in mind, but you could do it with one equation for each side.

Comment: i mean the formula of a sqaure is sound but other formulas i dont know if they are sound like the formula of a circle

Comment: To do a circle you use two equations: a parabola above and below the x axis. But you could easily Google this

Comment: the surface of circle

Comment: The surface area? You use the derivatives of the same two equations and calculate the integral from -R to +R (assuming it is centered at the origin). Ie, use calculus. Granted there are probably also proofs that don’t require calculus - but that’s an easy way to do it if you have taken calculus.

Comment: for example the formula of a trapezoid

Comment: @joseph lookup the definition and equations on Google. This is common, accessible knowledge.

Comment: ok im gonna gonna

Comment: i search the formula of triangles and they seem correct but the circle i dont know

Comment: @joseph you'll need to study more so that you can understand the proofs - or until you show an error in those proofs. There's no getting around putting in the time to study these things if you want to understand/challenge them

Comment: it takes time time

Comment: im not sur eabotu the formula of circle

Comment: Google it. Watch YouTube videos. Buy math books w proofs. Or ask on a math forum

Comment: im thinking about it

Comment: im researching im